# Create a custom Grid

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I want to create a new class inheriting from Grid, but it won't work for some reason, and I don't know why.

First I'm getting this error:

The application crashed: Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.

The topics I found for this didn't help me. And I don't know why "this" should be null. The line for this error is the Task.Delay(1) on the bottom code.

So basically I want to create a custom grid, inheriting from grid, so I can use to just like that, but with additional properties and some logics. The reason: I want to move some code from the visible page.xaml.cs to the Grid itself, so it can layout and do the rest, only important to itself, on its own.

But when I use it on my visible page in the .cs, it doesn't work. It's not necessary to be usable in the xaml.

I don't know if it is necessary to subclass Grid, or if it will be enough to create a class extension. Feel free to change my approach on that topic.

My Class looks like this:

CustomGrid.cs

```
namespace Solution
{
    class CustomGrid : Grid
    {
        private GridConfiguration config;
        MainViewModel mainViewModel;

        public CustomGrid(GridConfiguration initialConfig)
        {
            config = initialConfig;
            SetValue(RowProperty, config.Pos.Y);
            SetValue(ColumnProperty, config.Pos.X);
        }

        public void Unload()
        {

        }

        public void LoadAnotherConfig (GridConfiguration newConfig)
        {
            unload();
            config = newConfig;
        }

        private void setUpGrid()
        {
            switch (config.Type.ToLower())
                {
                    case "html":
                        GenerateWebView();
                        break;
                    case "pdf":
                        GeneratePdf();
                        break;
                    case "image":
                        GenerateImage();
                        break;
                    case "video":
                        GenerateVideo();
                        break;
                    default:
                        GeneratePlaceHolder();
                        break;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

And the place I am creating and adding them is here:

```
List<Dictionary> allCellsToPresent ) new List<Dictionary>();

private async void GeneratePage()
{
    foreach (var cellInfo in allCellsToPresent)
        {
            //create custom grid for each cellInfo
            CustomGrid grid = new CustomGrid(cellInfo);
            grid.SetUpGrid();
            Tapped += Grid_Tapped;
            MainGrid.Children.Add(grid);
        }
    await Task.Delay(100);
    ScrollViewer.ChangeView( 0, 0, 1, false);
}
```

The MainGrid is placed in a ScrollViewer for scrolling and zooming. And I have to wait for any Task.Delay so the previous started processes will be finished before animation, otherwise there are glitches during the animation because the MainGrid still adds some children and changes the ScrollViewers inner size.

Comment: You need to add the code with the line that crashes (or up the stack trace from your custom grid class). This is just a class definition.

Comment: Can I know the purpose behind creating a custom one, although the builtin does almost every thing.

Comment: The reason for creating a custom Grid is, that I want to move code out of my page with the main grid, because it has grown too big and I just want to create a custom Grid for each cell in my main grid. And the layout code should be in the custom grid, so it knows itself what to do with the data I give to it, like the config dictionary.

Comment: The line my app is exiting at is:
await Task.Delay(1000);
When that happens, the app just closes, and I am back in VS.
If I remove the line, it still crashes on that position, just the new line, it looks strange because there is nothing else happening then adding a background image, a webview or another element, depenting on the config.type. Currently there are only images and webviews. And ofcourse putting the new custom grids to their position, like
SetValue(RowProperty, config.Pos.Y);

Comment: Your code is not enough to reproduce your issue, if possible, please upload [mcve]. Even I'm not sure the above code you'are providing are right since you have code line `List<Dictionary> allCellsToPresent ) new List<Dictionary>();` which is obviously wrong. If you remove the `Task.Delay` but you still can receive the exception this should not be able break at this code line. So only a reproduce project can let people help you correctly.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to upload something for that.
But in general, is that the correct approach to do what I want to do?
I just want to add new Properties and a few layout functions to my CurstomGrid. If there is a better way to do so, instead of creating a CustomGrid that inherits from Grid, that would be good for me as well.

Comment: You can also try [custom panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/custom-panels-overview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sunsteen Wu's example in the comments for the custom panel did help me out. I had to change some elements but that was the minor deal.

Here it is again:

You can also try [custom panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/custom-panels-overview)  – Sunteen Wu - MSFT Feb 14 at 9:25